# How can I put a colored background to a figure

Tags: mdframed

I want to add a color to the background of an image that is not necesarly of the width of the paper.
Ive seen some answers related to this, but in all of them the backgrownd has the width of the paper (because the float has that width).
The solution should look like this: 
[image]

Is there a way to generaly fix the float width to the width of any figure I insert for the whole document? This figures have diferent widths.

Comment: The float width is always \columnwidth or \textwidth, but you don't have to use the whole thing.  You can either set or measure the image width and center it inside a minipage.  Personally, I would use tikz or tcolorbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two packages can set the width  of a figure to its natural width:

- `threeparttable` defines a `measuredfigure` environment.
- `floatrow` defines a `\ffigbox{\caption{mycaption}\label{mylabel}}{…}`, which accepts an optional argument for the width of `\ffigbox`. Its natural width is obtained with `[\FBwidth]`. But you also may obtain a slightly larger width, with, say `[1.25\FBwidth]`.

Comment: Hi Bernard,
Txs for the replay, i am very new at latex, is there a chance you can help me with an example code to obtain something similar to the image i have posted on my question?

Comment: @sacosent: I can help (hopefully…) if you can explain more explicitly (or post a hand-made sketch of what you want) where this background should be. The two above figures have three parts: a caption, the figure itself and notes under the figure. Ther should be a background behind what?